# How to scan the output string values run from another c program?

Tags: c

I am having a c program called summary.c , that will run another c program called flatfile.c , the faltfile.c after running will output and print 3 lines

1. the Q1 result is XX.
2. the Q2 result is XX.
3. the Q3 result is xx.

Is there any way that the summary.c after called the flatfile.c , it able to scan XX value then store as variable for the use in summary.c

I know for the summary.c it is able to called another c program by using "execve" however, i don't know how get the result from flatfile.c and store as variable inside the summary for further calculation.

I expect the summary.c after run it, it able to run flatfile.c and get the information it needed inside the summary.c It need to annoy "1. The Q1 result is " and also ignore "2. The Q2 result is " , get the value XX.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your code, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question. See the `popen` command for a simple approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what we want to do is run Q1 and Q2 in a pipeline, almost as though the starting command was `./Q1 | ./Q2`, but have Q1 do it. While the exec family of functions is necessary, it is not quite sufficient. Setting up the whole of the pipe is easy.

At the top of Q1:

```
int main()
{
    int pipefd[2];
    pid_t pid;
    pipe(&pipefd);
    if (0 == (pid = fork()) {
        close(pipefd[1]);
        dup2(pipefd[0], 0);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        execl("Q2", "Q2", ...);
        _exit(3);
    }
    dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
    close(pipefd[1]);
    close(pipefd[0]);

    /* any output with `printf()` is now input to Q2; anything with `fprintf(stderr)` still displays on screen */
}
```

Error handling mostly omitted for brevity. `pipe()`, `fork()`, and `execl()` can fail. With the first two, they return -1 for failure; if `execl()` returns at all you know it failed. I prefer `perror()` for error messages.

Answer (score 0):

suggest using the function: `popen()` in file: `summary.c` to start the second program: `flatfile.c`

This will allow the second program to pass back to the first program the results of the calculations of the calculated values for Q1, Q2, and Q3 via the second programs' `stdout`

Answer (score -1):

Considering your needs, you can try the following solutions:

1. If you are allowed to modify flatfile.c, why not wrap its main function as a common function *Func* that return these results as array of strings/structs/..., and call *Func* in summary.c
2. Suppose you can't modify flatfile.c, you man run execve like this `system("./flatfile >> results.txt")`, hopefully the output of flatfile will be redirected to results.txt, then you can simply read this file.

To get the value XX, you may use regex to match each line. So learn about regex in c.

Comment: I'm pretty sure './flatfile >> results.txt' is not the name of a program. Don't put shell redirections in `execve`. You appear to be trying to call `system()` but you have a long way to go to get to something that actually solves the problem.